# Get RSS Feed URL with .rss

Tags: rss, rss-feed

Is there a way to get the direct RSS Feed Url for new products?

I dont mean domain.com/rss/catalog/new/store_id/1/

I Mean domain.com/rss/catalog/new/store_id/1/RSSFEED.RSS

Thanks